# Count number of colored cells of a row in html table in a separate column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table having 32 number of columns and starting 31 column has feature that i can fill color after clicking on any cell.So i want to calculate the number of cells not colored and display it in the last column. Please use javascript only. Refer picture.

Comment: are you adding a class to color the table cell or are you adding inline css? Please add your HTML

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Keep book on clicked cells, and calculate a new sum in the click handler.

Comment: The whole table format is being made using this syntax:-
document.write("<td></td>");

Comment: A couple of rows of the table would be nice to see, as well as the click event handler, which colors the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
function set_random_color(){ /* for test only */
  var color_table = document.getElementById('color_table');
  var rnd_row_int = get_randon_cell_int();
  var rnd_color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  color_table.rows[rnd_row_int].cells[0].setAttribute('bgcolor', rnd_color);
  get_count_white_cells();
}

function get_randon_cell_int(){
   var color_table = document.getElementById('color_table');
   var rnd_row_int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (color_table.rows.length-1));
   var cell_bgcolor = color_table.rows[rnd_row_int].cells[0].getAttribute('bgcolor'); 
   if(!cell_bgcolor){
      return rnd_row_int;  
   }else{
      return get_randon_cell_int();
   }
}

function get_count_white_cells(){
  var white_cell_counter = 0;
  var color_table = document.getElementById('color_table');
  for (var i = 0; i < color_table.rows.length-1; i++) {
     var cell_bgcolor = color_table.rows[i].cells[0].getAttribute('bgcolor');
     if (!cell_bgcolor){
        white_cell_counter++;
        
     }
  }
  color_table.rows[color_table.rows.length-1].cells[0].innerHTML = white_cell_counter;
  
  if(white_cell_counter == 0){
     alert('all cells colored!!!');
     document.getElementById('btn_set_color').setAttribute('onclick', 'alert(\'all cells colored!\')');
  }
}
```

```css
table td {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn_set_color" value="set random cell color" onclick="set_random_color();">

<table border="1" id="color_table">
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, function 'get_count_white_cells()'  really helped after some changes.